# Rails, prevent deprecation warnings for Model.scoped, find(:all) and relation #all?

Tags: ruby, rspec, deprecated

I have tests that pass but display

```
$ rspec spec/event_calendar_spec.rb 
......DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead. (called from events_for_date_range at /home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/event_calendar/lib/event_calendar.rb:52)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #find(:all) is deprecated. Please call #all directly instead. You have also used finder options. These are also deprecated. Please build a scope instead of using finder options. (called from events_for_date_range at /home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/event_calendar/lib/event_calendar.rb:52)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from events_for_date_range at /home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/event_calendar/lib/event_calendar.rb:52)
```

The model is:

```
 50     # Get the events overlapping the given start and end dates
 51     def events_for_date_range(start_d, end_d, find_options = {})
 52       self.scoped(find_options).find(
 53         :all,
 54         :conditions => [ "(? <= #{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.end_at_field}) AND (#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field}< ?)", start_d.to_time.utc, end_d.to_time.utc ],
 55         :order => "#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field} ASC"
 56       )
 57     end
```

I tried a few varieties of removing .scoped, removing :all and using where but none seemed to work, for example:

```
 50     # Get the events overlapping the given start and end dates
 51     def events_for_date_range(start_d, end_d, find_options = {})
 52       self.all.where(find_options,
 53         :conditions => [ "(? <= #{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.end_at_field}) AND (#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field}< ?)", start_d.to_time.utc, end_d.to_time.utc ],
 54         :order => "#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field} ASC"
 55       ) 
 56     end
```

gave:

```
  expected: [#<CustomEvent id: 1, custom_start_at: "2013-10-27 13:12:00", custom_end_at: "2013-10-29 13:12:00">]
        got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CustomEvent id: 1, custom_start_at: "2013-10-27 17:12:00", custom_end_at: "2013-10-29 17:12
```

How can I update the find to not display the deprecation warnings?

Comment: have your tried my answer for using `load` vs. `all` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all` is implied, you don't need it when using scopes.

```
 50     # Get the events overlapping the given start and end dates
 51     def events_for_date_range(start_d, end_d, find_options = {})
 52       self.where(find_options,
 53         :conditions => [ "(? <= #{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.end_at_field}) AND (#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field}< ?)", start_d.to_time.utc, end_d.to_time.utc ],
 54         :order => "#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field} ASC"
 55       ) 
 56     end
```

You would only use `all` if you actually wanted all of the records: `CustomEvent.all`. If you are worried about default scopes, you could do something like this:

```
 50     # Get the events overlapping the given start and end dates
 51     def events_for_date_range(start_d, end_d, find_options = {})
 52       self.unscoped.where(find_options,
 53         :conditions => [ "(? <= #{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.end_at_field}) AND (#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field}< ?)", start_d.to_time.utc, end_d.to_time.utc ],
 54         :order => "#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field} ASC"
 55       ) 
 56     end
```

**If you are using `all` in rails 4 as a way to force eager loading, you should now use [load](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load)**:

```
 50     # Get the events overlapping the given start and end dates
 51     def events_for_date_range(start_d, end_d, find_options = {})
 52       self.where(find_options,
 53         :conditions => [ "(? <= #{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.end_at_field}) AND (#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field}< ?)", start_d.to_time.utc, end_d.to_time.utc ],
 54         :order => "#{self.quoted_table_name}.#{self.start_at_field} ASC"
 55       ).load
 56     end
```